# Preseed auto partition disk with no prompting only if disk is empty (no existing partition tables)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 18.04, preseed

Is it possible to setup a Ubuntu preseed for a one drive system, so that if the drive is empty (we can assume empty means it has no MBR or GPT partition tables) it goes right ahead and partitions it automatically, however if there are already partitions on the disk it prompts for manual partitioning?

This way I can quickly dd out the partition table of a disk, and just run the install to auto create, yet if somehow I ran the install perhaps by error on existing system it wouldn't just blindly format and setup new partitions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear possible [help.ubuntu.com - LTS Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs01.html):

> ### B.1.2. Limitations
>
> Although most questions used by debian-installer can be preseeded
> using this method, there are some notable exceptions. You must
> (re)partition an entire disk or use available free space on a disk; it
> is not possible to use existing partitions.

I'll dig around a bit more to see if someone has come up with a solution to the drawback.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, I see nobody else has. I think d-i preseed/early_command is the answer as this allows a script to run immediately before install, i.e. just after preseed downloaded.

I'll have a go later, set up a script that detects lack of partition tables, if they are not there dynamically change the pressed to add a automatic format entry for partitioning, otherwise leave empty which has same effect as manual intervention required.

Comment: It was interesting taking a look. I would like to see preseed elevated for more than cloning new workstations to attach to a server. For example I repeatedly upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 and it would be nice to start it without baby-sitting the prompts for new grub config or new vnstat config, etc.

Comment: I used to do a lot of preseeding using PXE, but mostly these days like to use modified mini.iso's to just grab the preseed from http.

In theory if this early_command works you could have a generic preseed and then do as many complicated things as you wanted in a script called by early_command to make an entirely new dynamic preseed. This could be automated (e.g. get data from server) or it could be semi-automated with a series of user prompts for basic details all on 1 screen before the install begins. Installing is not a problem as there is always coffee, the pain is babysitting a install.

Comment: @Jimmy You seem to really know your stuff. I think many users (including myself) would appreciate it if you wrote a self-answered question on using `preseed`. If you do, leave a comment here and I'll happily upvote both the question and answer you post.

Comment: I've got it working all in a very beta state which needs cleanup. There's the easier option of doing it just before partitioning, however I don't like that option as it takes a (little) while to get to the partitioning part. So I've invented a way to do it just as the installation starts.

I'll do a write-up on a blog I'm setting up (as I realise I have found a few unique discoveries to problems and it will be good for me to win contract work ) ) and will post here. ETA 2 weeks as I am very busy with work. Will award you the bounty as you at least took an interest. Cheers.